# Does C++ standard address the concept "TYPE"?

Tags: c++, class, types, standards, language-lawyer

I have been reading Design Patterns(GOF), and it presents a clear distinction between the class and the type of an object as specified below.

**The TYPE of the object is defined by it's interface(set of methods that it can handle) and the CLASS of the object defines its implementation.**

I have read in many books on C++ that **a Class is user-defined Type**. And nothing more has been mentioned about the concept TYPE (not even as GOF mentions it.)

I just want to know does C++ standard mentions anywhere the concept TYPE in any way if not the way that GOF mentions.

Or is it assumed that this difference is too basic to mention?

Answer (score 2):

C++ defines several kinds of types.  Class types are just one such kind of type; others are integral types, floating-point types, pointer types, array types, function types, and so forth. The concept of "type" is well defined in C++.

The C++ standard discusses types in section 3.9 [basic.types] (in the 2011 ISO C++ standard; the section number may be different in other editions).

The Design Patterns book is is not language-specific, and it's using the words "type" and "class" in a different way than the way the C++ standard uses them.